# Python| How can I make this variable global without initializing it as 'global'

Tags: python, global

I have this code here. The only part I can add code to is in main_____ AFTER the 'i=1' line. This script will be executing multiple times and will have some variable (might not be 'i', could be 'xy', 'var', anything), incrementing by 1 each time. I have gotten this to work by declaring 'i' as global above the method, but unfortunately, I can't keep it that way.

Is there a way in which I can make 'i' function as a global variable within the above-mentioned parameters?

```
def main______():
    try:
        i+=1
    except NameError:
        i=1 
main______()
```

Comment: "The only part I can add code to is in main_____ AFTER the 'i=1' line"  Really?  Why?  That makes approximately no sense at all.

Comment: And why are you calling the function main______()? That is exactly 6 underscores too many. This question is completely lacking in what must be a lot of really strange context. Don't ask abstract questions when you have concrete problems.

Comment: I tried to simplify a complex problem. The name of the method is irrelevant.

Comment: -1: After the edit the question became incomprehensible.  Don't know the variable name.  Can't change any code except in one poorly-chosen place.  Can't make any sense out of it at all.  There must be a much simpler explanation lurking under all this complexity.

Comment: @frank: You aren't simplifying a complex problem, you are removing all the context. You ask the question that is on your mind. That is usually the wrong question to ask. You need to tell us the concrete problem, not ask an abstract question that makes no sense.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question-on-so/25128#25128

Comment: Is this a homework problem? If not, why the restrictions? (Without the restrictions, I would probably use a generator solution, but that, I think, does require something like `while true` at the top.)

Comment: Sadly, no. It's part of a larger problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a global variable you have to declare it as global. What's wrong with that?

If you need to store state between calls, you should be using a class

```
>>> class F():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.i=0
...     def __call__(self):
...         print self.i
...         self.i+=1
... 
>>> f=F()
>>> f()
0
>>> f()
1
>>> f()
2
```

Comment: +1 the first one. Second one should go into a shredding machine.

Comment: -1: The hacky way is dangerously close to a bug.  Using mutable objects as default values is so dangerous that showing it here is trouble waiting to happen.  Even if it is correct.  It's still a bad thing.